# Facebook Ad behaving buggy

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads

What I want: Publish a facebook Ad with a CTA with a custom link to one of my pages of my homepage. So, if my homepage is `mydomain.com`; I want the CTA button of my facebook ad to link to for example `mydomain.com/mypages/registernow?utm_source=facebook&campaign_id=12`.

What I tried: Simply to create a new campaign in the facebook ads manager, specified the URL mentioned above, and saved. It all worked, but once the campaign got published, the CTA button links to `mydomain.com`.

I know this is not a question that has anything to do with coding, but thought of asking it here still, as there are may some developers having experience with this issue / how the provided facebook ad URLs are parsed and eventually disabled / automatically replaced with the root URL.. ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with coding

Comment: Eventually it has, as it's potentially related to URL - parsing of the facebook developer environment. I did not want to exclude that possibility, hence my question. Except you can demonstrate that this is indeed not related to any code?

Comment: It is not related to your code because you haven't written any. If Facebook has problem with their code they are welcome to post here and ask about their problem.

Comment: Can you demonstrate that? What if you need to write URLs with parameters in a special way or what not. I wouldn't be so harshe on closing tbh...

Comment: Also, if you may know about a community which is a much better fit for my question, plz just let me know.. Their help / support pages / forums are a disaster.

Comment: I'd start by putting your URL through the Facebook debug tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), and see if og:url or canonical perhaps make it point back to the domain root or something.